# Rust compiler keeps trait method that is always inlined

Tags: rust, traits, compiler-optimization, inlining

I’ve found that if I implement methods for a private type, then the methods stay in the compiler output even if the compiler automatically inlines all of the calls to those methods. The only way I’ve found to make it remove the methods from the compiler output is to annotate the method implementation with `#[inline(always)]`. That’s not too much of a hassle, but I’m curious why it’s necessary. For an example of this in action, consider the following bit of code:

```
// Note: In this example I’m implementing a method from an external trait,
//       but the same behavior happens for locally defined traits

use std::ops::Mul;

pub fn foo(x: u64, y: u64) -> u64 {
    let a = Matrix {
        value: [[x, x], [y, y]]
    };
    let b = Matrix {
        value: [[x, y], [x, y]]
    };
    let c = a * b;
    c.value[0][0]
}

struct Matrix {
    value: [[u64; 2]; 2]
}

impl Mul for Matrix {
    type Output = Self;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        let a = self.value;
        let b = rhs.value;
        let mut c = [[0; 2]; 2];
        c[0][0] = a[0][0] * b[0][0] + a[0][1] * b[1][0];
        c[0][1] = a[0][0] * b[0][1] + a[0][1] * b[1][1];
        c[1][0] = a[1][0] * b[0][0] + a[1][1] * b[1][0];
        c[1][1] = a[1][0] * b[0][1] + a[1][1] * b[1][1];
        Self {
            value: c
        }
    }
}
```

We have a private type `Matrix`, an implementation of `Mul` for it, and a public function that takes two integers, makes two matrices using those integers, multiplies them, and returns the top left entry in the resulting matrix.

When I put this in the [Compiler Explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/q4h7KM8eG) and compile with `-C opt-level=[anything but 0]`, the compiler inlines the call to `Mul` and then optimizes away the matrix multiplication entirely, and `foo` ends up looking like this:

```
example::foo:
        imul    rdi, rdi
        lea     rax, [rdi + rdi]
        ret
```

This is exactly what I would expect. The weird part is that in addition to the assembly for `foo`, the compiler output includes the instructions for `mul`. This seems unnecessary. The compiler inlined every call to `mul`, so the program never actually uses the assembly instruction `call` to jump to where `mul` is defined. So leaving the instructions for `mul` in the compiled binary seems like a pure waste of space. Indeed, if I annotate `mul` with `#[inline(always)]`, then the compiler outputs only the instructions for `foo`. Why is it that I would need to annotate with `#[inline(always)]` in order to eliminate the instructions for the method from the compiler output?

Comment: If I move that `mul()` to an inherent method of `Matrix` and make that function private, then it will erase the code for `mul()`, so I'm guessing that the compiler keeps the code around just in case some other module decides to call it non-inlinely.

Comment: I had also noticed that. But even as I have it written, no external code can call `mul()` on a `Matrix` because the whole `Matrix` type is private. That makes me think it’s a bug where the fact that the `Mul` trait is public makes the compiler miss that `mul()` for `Matrix` is (de facto) private. But maybe there’s a good reason why it has to be that way.

Comment: But you could somewhere a `dyn Mul`, or maybe a `dyn X where X: Mul` or something like that. Maybe the compiler only omits the code when it is totally sure that it will never be needed. Or maybe if you link with `lto=true` it is removed from the final executable?

Comment: Compiling with `lto=true` does not make it omit the code. For the `dyn` idea, I’m still not sure how that could make a difference. Even if external code uses a `dyn Mul` and imports as much as it can from the snippet above, I still don’t see how it could have a `Matrix` to call `mul()` on.

Comment: @rodrigo: In GCC at least, I'm not sure `-flto` is the same as `-fwhole-program` in terms of promising that nothing that isn't being linked now will try to reference the symbol.  A Linux PIE executable is also a shared object, so you can in theory link more code with one.  I don't know Rust or linkers well enough to be sure if this is a missed-optimization or necessary because of some corner case, or if there's a way to work around it.

Comment: Compiler Explorer might not be the best source of information: it keeps all `pub` functions, i.e. it keeps `Matrix::mul` because `core::ops::arith::Mul::mul` is `pub` and thus is your implementation of it.

Comment: Take a look at this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e1f89ea51afbe69992ae216d0c998383). Here the code for `Matrix::mul()` is removed, but if you rename the `main()` function to `mainx()` it will re-apperar. That is because Playground uses the presence of  `main` to compile an executable or a library. In an executable the function is removed, in a library it is not. I think that there may be corner cases where this function may be need somewhere, when weird monomorphizations and/or dynamic dispatching or whatever...

Comment: @PeterCordes: "A Linux PIE executable is also a shared object, so you can in theory link more code with one." Yes, but I'm think that all Rust symbols have visibility=hidden unless they are declared `export`, so they would still be inaccesible from another ELF modules.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks! While I’m still not totally clear on what’s going on here, at least I know that I don’t have to write `#[inline(always)]` to remove unneeded code from my binaries. Also very good to know that Playground can show assembly. I thought it was only for running, but it’s nice to know I don’t need to have separate tools for those two tasks.